# Cloud watch Log insights query, combining two querires

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I currently use two different cloud watch log insights queries one to get total request count and the other to get total error count. Below are the queries:

**Total count:**

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /reply.*MyAPI/
|parse @message '"reqID":*' as reqID
| stats count_distinct(reqID) as request_count by bin(1h) as hour
```

** Error count**

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /reply.*MyAPI.*Exception/
|parse @message '"reqID":*' as reqID
| stats count_distinct(reqID) as request_count by bin(1h) as hour
```

However I would like to calculate both total request counts and error request count in each bin and calculate error rates for each bin (`error count`/`total request count`) if possible with a single query. How would I go about this?